# Reading images from file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have bmp images in image folder on my computer. I named it from `1.bmp` to `100.bmp`.

And I want to read these images like this:

```
for i=1:100
    s='C:\images'+i+'.bmp';
    A=imread(s);
end
```

But Matlab gave an error. How can I implement this?

Comment: yalcin, stop it. it's a beginner's question and should be tagged accordingly. there's no shame in asking or answering beginner's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>  for i=1:100
>      s=strcat('C:\images',num2str(i),'.bmp');
>      try                                                  
>        A=imread(s);
>      catch
>      end 
>    end
```

here i am using num2str which is used for convert the data type of number to string and i am using try for aviod the error because if file is not there then it will aviod that error.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `sprintf` function

```
s = sprintf('c:\images%d.bmp', i);
A = imread(s);
```

You can read more about string handling in matlab [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strings.html)

Comment: The \ inside the sprintf format string should be escaped as '\\'.

Answer (score 5):

Create `s` in the following way:

```
s = ['C:\images\' int2str(i) '.bmp'];
```

Also, your loop will simply keep overwriting `A`, so you will instead have to make it a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) to store all 100 images. Do this outside your loop:

```
A = cell(1,100);
```

and then load your images in the loop like so:

```
A{i} = imread(s);
```

Answer (score 3):

let me guess. you don't have files named `C:\images1.bmp`. Oh, that's not the error you're getting, but it will be the next one, once you follow [ypnos's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158362/reading-images-from-file-in-matlab/1158371#1158371).

Comment: Good catch on the additional error, but ypnos' answer actually doesn't work. ;)

Comment: @SilentGhost: You're right. His answer won't throw an error... it will just mangle the file name even further, leading to the same error. =)

Comment: Oooops, my fault! Didn't think it through. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
imgfiles=dir('c:\images\*.*');
for k=1:length(imgfiles)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your folder to the matlab directory path and run the following commands.

`files=dir('*.bmp')
for k=1:numel(files)
    I=imread(files(k).name);
end`

I am using these commands to read the image files.