# How I read  mat format files from folder in matlab?

Tags: matlab

My question I have folder contains the images in mat format how I can read these mat files using for loop ???

Comment: You are asking the same question again and again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618696/how-i-can-read-images-from-multiple-folder-in-matlab/10618886#10618886, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158362/reading-images-from-file-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
folder = 'C:/foobar/';
files = dir([folder '*.mat');
for i = 1:numel(files)
    load(files(i).name;
end
```

Comment: Why downvote a 4 year old answer without even commenting what's wrong with it?